# Regarding Proverbs 15:3 - How many Eyes (עֵינֵ֣י) does God have?

Tags: proverbs, attributes-of-god

The Hebrew Bible claims **"the Eyes of YHVH" (עֵינֵ֣י יְהוָ֑ה)** are everywhere, in the scroll of "Mishlei" (Proverbs) - chapter 15 verse 3.

**Proverbs 15:3 [MT]**

> "The eyes of YHVH are everywhere, viewing the evil and the good." (בְּֽכָל־מָ֖קוֹם עֵינֵ֣י יְהוָ֑ה צֹ֜פ֗וֹת רָעִ֥ים וְטוֹבִֽים)

**Based on Proverbs 15:3 - How many Eyes (עֵינֵ֣י) does God have?**

Comment: [Link](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/עיני).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase "eyes of the LORD" in the OT is frequent and denotes several things including:

- God's omniscience; Prov 22:12, 2 Chron 16:9
- God's righteous judgement of actions; Amos 9:8, 1 Kings 15:5, Judges 3:12, 2 Chron 27:2, 29:6, 2 Chron 34:2
- God's watch care of His people; Deut 11:12, Prov 15:3, Judges 6:1, 13:1

Fascinatingly, Zechariah contains two references to a specific number of the LORD's eyes, namely Seven.

- Zech 4:10 - For who has despised the day of small things? But these **seven eyes** of the LORD, which scan the whole earth, will rejoice when they see the plumb line in the hand of Zerubbabel.”

These highly symbolic seven eyes are actually introduced in the previous chapter as a metaphor of the God's omniscience

- Zech 3:9 - See the stone I have set before Joshua; on that one stone are **seven eyes**. Behold, I will engrave on it an inscription, declares the LORD of Hosts, and I will remove the iniquity of this land in a single day.

It is as if the LORD is combined into a dual metaphor of both the "rock" and the completely seeing (omniscient) seeing seven eyes.

Even more interestingly, the NT takes up this same metaphor in Revelation as a symbol of Christ:

- Rev 5:6 - Then I saw a Lamb who appeared to have been slain, standing in the center of the throne, encircled by the four living creatures and the elders. The Lamb had seven horns and **seven eyes**, which represent the seven Spirits of God sent out into all the earth.

The allusion to Zechariah is unmistakable!  The number seven presumably represents completeness, in this case of seeing or knowledge, or in more technical speak: omniscience.

Comment: Todah (תֹּודָה), Dottard! - This is an excellent collection of references to the "Eyes of YHVH" in both the Tanakh & New Testament. * It is interesting to learn John's [Revelation] makes a parallel of the 7 Eyes of YHVH" with the "7 Eyes of the Lamb".

Answer (score 3):

The eyes here is symbolic of God's omnipresence and omniscience. It is not to be taken literally. Another example is in

> Hebrews 4:13
> Nothing in all creation is hidden from God's sight; everything is uncovered and exposed before the **eyes** of Him to whom we must give account.

Based solely on Proverbs 15:3 - How many eyes does God have? Infinite.